# Getting 401 unauthorized error while perform maven release

Tags: java, xml, maven

I want to release the Jenkins plugin through the local machine, but while performing                        "mvn release: perform" through the command line it says unauthorized error 401. I tried many things to fix this but didn't work.

Getting error like this
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project autonomiq: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact io.jenkins.plugins:autonomiq:hpi:1.10 from/to maven.jenkins-ci.org (https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/): Transfer failed for https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/io/jenkins/plugins/autonomiq/1.10/autonomiq-1.10.hpi 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]

pom.xml file

4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.16</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<groupId>io.jenkins.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>autonomiq</artifactId>
<version>1.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>hpi</packaging>
<name>autonomiq plugin</name>
<url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/autonomiq-plugin</url>
<description>Plugin to support Autonomiq tests</description>
<properties>
    <jenkins.version>2.303.1</jenkins.version>
    <java.level>8</java.level>
</properties>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>MIT License</name>
        <url>https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
    </license>
</licenses>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>structs</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-step-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-cps</artifactId>
        <version>2.39</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-job</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-basic-steps</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-durable-task-step</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>workflow-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>credentials</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<developers>
  <developer>
    <id>jameeluddin</id>
    <name>Mohammed Jameel Uddin</name>
    <email>jameeluddin30@gmail.com</email>
  </developer>
</developers>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/jenkinsci/Autonomiq-plugin.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:jenkinsci/Autonomiq-plugin.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/jenkinsci/Autonomiq-plugin</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
        <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repo.jenkins-ci.org</id>
        <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
```

~/.m2/settings.xml file.

```
<server>
  <username>puneetchelani_sauce</username>
  <password>REDACTED</password>
  <id>central</id>
</server>
<server>
  <username>puneetchelani_sauce</username>
  <password>REDACTED</password>
  <id>snapshots</id>
</server>
```

`

Comment: You are using HTTPS (secure) which uses TLS to encrypt the data.  Error 401 can indicate the TLS encryption is failing.  What machine are you using to run code? Older machine may need updates to work with latest version of TLS.  TLS also uses certificates and the certificates may be missing.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler may help.  TLS has a certificate block with the version of TLS being used.  TLS the server send a list of valid certificate names from server to client.  the client need to use one of the certificates in the list for TLS to work.

Comment: @jdweng, why would TLS issues end up with 401? TLS happens before HTTP and there are no status codes involved. You'd end up with TLS handshake errors.

Comment: You have issues with server credentials. Either that user doesn't have enough permissions or the creds are wrong, or wrong settings.xml is used or server names don't match with distributionManagement (which doesn't seem the case from what you showed).